# Accessing OBB files from C++

Tags: android, android-ndk, apk

I have a large game(50mb+), so I need to use APK Extension library provided by Google.

I've managed to work out the downloading part, but now I'd need to know the best way to access the .obb file from the native side.

There's [ZipResourceFile](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html#ZipLib), but how does one use that efficiently from C++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike Assets, files in ExternalStorage can be accessed with ordinary posix functions. All I need is to get the correct path to the Obb-file.

Directory can be figured out this way:

```
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String path = root.toString() + Constants.EXP_PATH + getPackageName();
```

And the file name is figured out out like this:

```
String filename = isMainFile ? "main." : "patch.") + versionCode + "." + getPackageName() + ".obb"
```

Comment: This does not look like NDK (C++) as you mentioned in your question. Could you give an NDK example? Thanks!

Comment: You can use ordinary POSIX file operations with NDK. The problem was I didn't know where the file would be. I assumed I had to access it with something like AssetManager. But it turned out that it's easily accessible once you know the path. My answer shows how to find out the path.

Comment: Here's how you read the file once you know the path: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: And this is how you pass the filepath from JAVA to C++ as string: http://electrofriends.com/articles/jni/jni-part-4-jni-strings/

Comment: So if I understand correctly, to access the content inside that OBB, I'd have to use JNI? The mountObb-based NDK methods don't seem to work properly. I can't reliably mount the OBB file as an image. So I guess the only "useable" OBB at the moment is a zip file, and there is no zipResourceFile API in NDK as far as I know....

Comment: @kakyo I'm having the same problem, did you find a way to find the path from NDK? (and also read a zip package)

Comment: Would this help? https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___storage.html#gaa5037fe4c0d785a50fc62ac2de9844c3